# Parity of number of pieces on the black squares of a chessboard

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle, chessboard

On a chess board there is an odd number of pieces in each row and in each column. What can we say about the total number of pieces on a black square on the board?

1. The number must be even.
2. The number must be odd.
3. The number can be either both even or odd.

Comment: $2)$ can be ruled out with the constellation $a1-b2-c3\cdots h8$

Comment: I guess a parity-argument shows $1)$, but I have no clue yet how.

Answer (score 5):

Orient the board so that a white square is in the top left hand corner. Label each square with a piece on it with $1$, and $0$ otherwise. Let $R_1,R_2,\ldots, R_8$ be the rows, and $C_1,C_2,\ldots, C_8$ be the columns.

[image: Chessboard labeled as above]

Add together $R_1+R_3+R_5+R_7+C_1+C_3+C_5+C_7$, which is even. Each white square in these squares gets accounted for $2$ times, so they have an even contribution to the sum. So this leaves the black squares, and an even minus an even is even, and all the black squares are accounted for exactly once, so there are an even number of pieces on the black squares.

The answer is $1$).

Comment: Ï thought this worked, but then I drew the diagram and I couldn't follow your reasoning.  If the square at $\langle R_1, C_1\rangle$ is black, then your $R_1+R_3+\ldots+C_1+\ldots$ decomposition counts each white square once, not twice.  And if $\langle R_1, C_1\rangle$ is white, then some white squares get counted twice and some not at all.   [Image here](https://ibb.co/mt9o5S)

Comment: hi, thank you for the answer. i think you meant: R2+R4+...+R8+C1+...+C7, right?

Comment: @omer that's the same, if you just put a different color square in the upper-left corner.

Comment: @MJD you must orient the board so that awhitesquare is in the top left hand corner, ill update. It doesnt matter if some whites dont get counted, it only matters that the one that are counted have an even contribution to the sum

Comment: @Omer I updated my answer, that is correct if the top left hand corner is  black.

Comment: I got it now, thanks!

Comment: @ultrainstinct let me edit just a second

Comment: @ultrainstinct just to make sure that i understand, can you claim this explaination: if a white square on  a chessboard is in Row R and column  C than R and C have the samepairty. if the square is black, R and C have different pairty (i suppose of course that the top left square is white, C1 is the column on the left, R1 is the highest row) .  so, if we take R1+R3+...+C1+..., so every white square that was counted was counted twice. and every black square was counted exactly once, so after some trivial algebra we get that the number of black pieces is even. am i right?

Comment: @Omer The latter half of your argument is basically correct. I don't know if this is what you meant but, we picked the rows and columns we added strategically. Specifically,  we picked the rows and columns such that, every black square gets accounted for exactly once, and the white squares in these rows and columns are accounted for exactly twice.

Comment: @ultrainstinct: Very nice! And thanks to MJD for the picture, which makes the proof very clear.

Comment: @ultrainstinct yeah, i think i got it :) thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If diagonals are all black, $B$ should be always odd. Else if diagonals are all white, $B $ should be even. Assume the former case. Because there are odd number of pieces, the chess board is of size $(2n+1)×(2n+1)$. Let the position of $i$-th piece be $(a_i , b_i)$ $(1\le i \le 2n+1) $. Then it is on the black square if $a_i +b_i $ is even and on the white square otherwise. Then $S:=\sum_{i=1}^{2n+1} {(a_i +b_i )} $ is odd if $B$ is even and $S $ is even if $B$ is odd. But as pieces are on each row and each column, $S=\sum_{i=1}^{2n+1}{(i+i)}$ is even. Hence $B $ must be odd.

Comment: not true. $8$ black pieces on black diagonal is even number, but each row/column has $1$ piece

Comment: Ramansa is considering a more general case.  The first sentence says “If diagonals are all black”.  This occurs on a square board with _odd_ side length.

Comment: As there are odd number of pieces, diagonal must have odd number of squares, not 8.

Comment: no, there is an odd number of pieces on each row and column. at least, that's how I understand the question.